# Regroup lines of a data frame for which a column value is inferior to x

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this data frame :

```
> df
    Z freq        proba
1  17    1 0.0033289263
2  18    4 0.0055569026
3  19    2 0.0087878028
4  20    3 0.0132023556
5  21   16 0.0188900561
6  22   12 0.0257995234
7  23   30 0.0337042731
8  24   41 0.0421963455
9  25   56 0.0507149437
10 26   65 0.0586089198
11 27   65 0.0652230449
12 28   93 0.0699913154
13 29   82 0.0725182432
14 30   94 0.0726318551
15 31   72 0.0703990113
16 32   74 0.0661024717
17 33   58 0.0601873020
18 34   66 0.0531896431
19 35   38 0.0456625487
20 36   45 0.0381117389
21 37   27 0.0309498221
22 38   17 0.0244723502
23 39   15 0.0188543771
24 40   13 0.0141629367
25 41    4 0.0103793600
26 42    1 0.0074254435
27 43    2 0.0051886582
28 45    1 0.0023658767
29 46    1 0.0015453804
30 49    2 0.0003792308

# Here are my datas :
> dput(df)
structure(list(Z = c(17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 
27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 
43, 45, 46, 49), freq = c(1, 4, 2, 3, 16, 12, 30, 41, 56, 65, 
65, 93, 82, 94, 72, 74, 58, 66, 38, 45, 27, 17, 15, 13, 4, 1, 
2, 1, 1, 2), proba = c(0.0033289262662263, 0.00555690264007235, 
0.00878780282243439, 0.0132023555702843, 0.0188900560866825, 
0.0257995234198431, 0.0337042730520012, 0.0421963455163949, 0.0507149437492447, 
0.0586089198012906, 0.0652230449359029, 0.0699913153996099, 0.0725182432348992, 
0.0726318551493006, 0.0703990113442269, 0.0661024716831246, 0.0601873020200862, 
0.0531896430528685, 0.045662548708844, 0.0381117389181843, 0.030949822142559, 
0.0244723501557229, 0.01885437705459, 0.0141629366839816, 0.0103793599644779, 
0.00742544354411115, 0.00518865818999788, 0.00236587669133322, 
0.00154538036835848, 0.000379230768851682)), .Names = c("Z", 
"freq", "proba"), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = "data.frame")
```

And I want to regroup lines for which the value "freq" is < 5 with the next line, and this while the next line is < 5.
Idk if I'm clear enough so this is the output I expect :

```
> df2
   labels effectifs         pi
1   17;20        10 0.03087599
2      21        16 0.01889006
3      22        12 0.02579952
4      23        30 0.03370427
5      24        41 0.04219635
6      25        56 0.05071494
7      26        65 0.05860892
8      27        65 0.06522304
9      28        93 0.06999132
10     29        82 0.07251824
11     30        94 0.07263186
12     31        72 0.07039901
13     32        74 0.06610247
14     33        58 0.06018730
15     34        66 0.05318964
16     35        38 0.04566255
17     36        45 0.03811174
18     37        27 0.03094982
19     38        17 0.02447235
20     39        15 0.01885438
21     40        13 0.01416294
22  41;49        11 0.02728395
```

I did it with nested `while`, but I find this solution very painful and so unoptimized.

```
i <- 1
freqs <- c()
labels <- c()
pi <- c()
while(i < nrow(df)) {
  if (df$freq[i] >= 5) {
    freqs <- c(freqs, df$freq[i])
    labels <- c(labels, df$Z[i])
    pi <- c(pi, df$proba[i])
    i <- i + 1
  }
  else {
    count <- df$freq[i]
    countPi <- df$proba[i]
    k <- i
    j <- i
    while(df$freq[i] < 5 & i < nrow(df)) {
      if (df$freq[i+1] < 5) {
        count <- count + df$freq[i+1]
        countPi <- countPi + df$proba[i+1]
        j <- i + 1
      }
      i <- i + 1
    }
    labels <- c(labels, paste0(df$Z[k], ";", df$Z[j]))
    freqs <- c(freqs, count)
    pi <- c(pi, countPi)
  }
}

df2 <- data.frame(labels, freqs, pi)
```

I'm sure there is far better, maybe with dplyr. If you have a better solution.. Thanks !

Comment: Based on the expected output, your first four lines (freq <5) are grouped together.  Is there a typo? ie. 17-20, instead of 17-21 and also the next line 16 16 implies that from that line onwards, the two columns will be the `freq` values

Comment: Yes, you are right I used `df$freq[i])` instead of `df$Z[i]` for labels and there was a mistake, it's 17-20 not 17-21. Edited, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use the "devel" version of "data.table" as new functions are introduced (`rleid`).  Here, we convert the "data.frame" to "data.table" (`setDT(df)`), create a grouping variable ("gr") based on the logical index (`freq <5`) using `rleid`.  'Z' column is 'numeric/integer' class.  Create a character column ("Z1") from the "Z".  Grouped by 'gr', if the "freq" is less than 5 for all the elements of that group, summarise the rows to a single row by taking the first observation of columns (`.SD[1L]`), remove the unwanted columns (as .SD includes "Z1" which will result in duplicate columns), append it with the "Z1" that we get from pasting the `min` and `max` value of "Z" for that group. Otherwise, leave it unchanged (`else .SD`).  Remove the columns that we don't need by assigning it to "NULL".

```
library(data.table) #data.table_1.9.5
res <- setDT(df)[, gr:=rleid(freq<5)][, Z1:= as.character(Z)][, 
        if(all(freq<5)) c(.SD[1L][,-4, with=FALSE], 
          list(Z1=toString(c(min(Z), max(Z)))))
      else .SD, gr][,1:2 :=NULL][]
head(res,3)
#   freq       proba     Z1
#1:    1 0.003328926 17, 20
#2:   16 0.018890056     21
#3:   12 0.025799523     22
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution ! Works great but a little unclear at first sight for a not "data.table" user, i'll work on it. Thanks !

Comment: @JulienNavarre I will update the post with some explanation. I was trying for some easier solutions to update.  So, got distracted

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) question, here is a `dplyr` solution. First I used a grouping function in order to define the groups (similar to the `rleid` function in `data.table`). Then the summary and is fairly simple.

```
# grouping function
grouping <- function(condition){
  # calculate runs for grouping
  run <- rle((!condition) * 1:length(condition))
  # revalue 
  run$values <- seq_along(run$values)
  # invert to get grouping
  inverse.rle(run)
}
# load dplyr
require(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(group = grouping(freq<5)) %>%               # add groups
  group_by(group) %>%                                # group data 
  summarize(freq = sum(freq),                        # sum freq
            proba = sum(proba),                      # sum proba
            Z = toString(unique(range(Z)))) %>%      # rename Z
  mutate(group=NULL)                                 # remove groups
## Source: local data table [22 x 3]
## 
##    freq      proba      Z
## 1    10 0.03087599 17, 20
## 2    16 0.01889006     21
## 3    12 0.02579952     22
## 4    30 0.03370427     23
## 5    41 0.04219635     24
## 6    56 0.05071494     25
## 7    65 0.05860892     26
## 8    65 0.06522304     27
## 9    93 0.06999132     28
## 10   82 0.07251824     29
## ..  ...        ...    ...
```